# Magento does not show price on a product page after Magmi import

Tags: magento, magmi

After using [Magmi (Magento Mass Importer)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/magmi/) for import products or update existing products is problem with price.

On the product page of the non-admin store-view I use, the price not appearing.

But if I open the product manually at the back-end (admin store-view) and save it .... price appears on the front-end store-view.

I tried to re-index everything, flash the Magento chache. But the problem still persist.

Magento is 1.9.0.1

Comment: Try to create a sample product and assign it price in admin itself and see if price is visible or not?

Comment: Have you checked the stock quantity after import?

Comment: Magmi import has bug when you use in your site. Revert import. Update Magmi. Import again. Still broken? Report bug (don't ask on Stackoverlow, it's the wrong site to report a problem). If not broken, write answer documenting the version you had with the bug and the version with which it worked.